# Powershell runbook AzureAutomation - SystemManagedIdentity

Tags: powershell, azure-automation

I created a script to disable and remove our stale communication clients in our AAD. When I created the script a year ago we used the "Azure Run As account" for this to run the script. Now we need to migrate the account to a "system assigned managed identity" and I experience some rights issues.

The following error message appears:
`Set-AzureADDevice` : Error occurred while executing SetDevice Code: Request_BadRequest Message: Properties other than ExtendedAttribute1..15 can be modified only on windows devices.

I added the "Contributor" to the "system assigned managed identity" and "subscription".

Connection method:

```
# Connect Azure-AD
$azureContext = Connect-AzAccount -Identity
$azureContext = Set-AzContext -SubscriptionName $azureContext.context.Subscription -DefaultProfile $azureContext.context
$graphToken = Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl "https://graph.microsoft.com/"
$aadToken = Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl "https://graph.windows.net"
Connect-AzureAD -AccountId $azureContext.account.id -TenantId $azureContext.tenant.id -AadAccessToken $aadToken.token -MsAccessToken $graphToken.token
```

Comment: As per my understanding, you are able to connect Azure AD with the help of above script but not able to use `set-AzureADDevice`. Is this correct? @R3M0NN

Answer (score 0):

> Set-AzureADDevice : Error occurred while executing SetDevice Code: Request_BadRequest Message: Properties other than ExtendedAttribute1..15 can be modified only on windows devices.

The error clearly states that few properties of `set-AzureADDevice` are only applicable to **"windows"** devices and not on `non-Windows OS` like ubuntu etc...

This is related to the `Azure AD device management API's` limitations and the way it handles different device types. The properties between `ExtendedAttributes1` and `ExtendedAttributes15` are device-specific and can be changed across all device types.

*You can use the below condition to check the OS type and update the device accordingly.*

```
$windowsDevicesList = Get-AzureADDevice | Where-Object { $_.DeviceOSType -eq "Windows" }
foreach ($dev in $windowsDevicesList) { 
  Set-AzureADDevice -ObjectId $dev.ObjectId -DisplayName "xxxx" 
}
```

***It retrieves only Windows type devices as shown.***

[image]

After checking all the above, I've used `set-AzureADDevice` command on windows operating systems and it worked as expected.

```
$azureContext = Connect-AzAccount -Identity
$azureContext = Set-AzContext -SubscriptionName $azureContext.context.Subscription -DefaultProfile $azureContext.context
$graphToken = Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl "https://graph.microsoft.com/"
$aadToken = Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl "https://graph.windows.net"
Connect-AzureAD -AccountId $azureContext.account.id -TenantId $azureContext.tenant.id -AadAccessToken $aadToken.token -MsAccessToken $graphToken.token
Set-AzureADDevice -ObjectId "b251xxxxxx" -DisplayName "jahnavivm"
```

***Output:***

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is working. But now I have still the issue to manage Android and iOS devices in our AAD tenant. We will remove the stale clients there, but it's not working anymore now with the System Assigned Managed Identity. Do you also know a solution for that?

Comment: Give OS type for `IOS` devices in the same way as detailed in the above answer. @R3M0NN